# Get smallest three values and keys in Excel formula

Tags: excel-formula

Suppose I have a table in Excel (2016) consisting of names in column A, and a count in column B, like this:

[image: Table]

I would now want to get the names of the lowest three counts. In this case, I would want my output to look like:

[image]

If there would be no duplicates in the data, this could be achieved with

```
=INDEX(A2:A11, MATCH(SMALL(B2:B11, 1), B2:B11, 0))
=INDEX(A2:A11, MATCH(SMALL(B2:B11, 2), B2:B11, 0))
=INDEX(A2:A11, MATCH(SMALL(B2:B11, 3), B2:B11, 0))
```

But with the duplicates in the count column, this would result in "Wiley, Ruby, Ruby", instead of "Wiley, Ruby, Sara". How could I achieve this second result in Excel 2016 (not having access to the `SORT`-function)?

Comment: There are solutions to this already on here, please do a search and they **are** here so you should have no problem finding them. Try top 5 avoiding duplicates...

Comment: [Chip Pearson](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/rank.aspx) also explains it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used a helper column to solve the issue of having two Names with the same count.

The helper column has combined the count with the name such as **20Vivyan**.

Then you can use the following **array formula** to look up the name and count coins by the rank:

For name: `{=INDEX(Column_Name,MATCH(Lookup_Rank,COUNTIF(Column_Helper,"<="&Column_Helper),0))}`

For count: `{=INDEX(Column_Count,MATCH(Lookup_Rank,COUNTIF(Column_Helper,"<="&Column_Helper),0))}`

> **COUNTIF** can be used to 'rank' text strings alphanumerically.

[image: Answer]

P.s. COUNTIF will not work if you tried to 'hide' the combined range in a **name**, nor will work if you used `B2:B11&A2:A11` instead of the combined range `C2:C11` in the formula.